# Spark: commit kafka offsets on end of batch

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

versions:

- spark 2.2
- kafka 0.11

according to [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html) to commit offsets in kafka I should use:

`stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)`

As result offsets are committed only on start of next batch. That cause 'constant' lag.

Is there any workaround to commit offsets at the end of current batch (but still use the same kafka group for offsets)?

example of lag monitoring:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any workaround to commit offsets at the end of current batch

Not via the `commitAsync` API. What the method call does is queue up the offsets to be committed, and then during `DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute` does the asynchronous commit:

```
override def compute(validTime: Time): Option[KafkaRDD[K, V]] = {
  val untilOffsets = clamp(latestOffsets())

  // Create KafkaRDD and other irrelevant code

  currentOffsets = untilOffsets
  commitAll()
  Some(rdd)
}
```

Where `commitAll` just polls the queue being filled up by `commitAsync`:

```
protected def commitAll(): Unit = {
  val m = new ju.HashMap[TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata]()
  var osr = commitQueue.poll()
  while (null != osr) {
    val tp = osr.topicPartition
    val x = m.get(tp)
    val offset = if (null == x) { osr.untilOffset } else { Math.max(x.offset, osr.untilOffset) }
    m.put(tp, new OffsetAndMetadata(offset))
    osr = commitQueue.poll()
  }
  if (!m.isEmpty) {
    consumer.commitAsync(m, commitCallback.get)
  }
}
```

Thus, unfortunately, if you want to commit the offsets as a transaction, you're going to have to store them separately in your own store and not use the built in offset commit tracking by Kafka.

Comment: You mentioned transactions. Do you mean that if I don't care about transactional processing, there is other possibilities?

Comment: @Natalia If you don't mind at least once processing semantics, then committing the offsets at the next iteration shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: the problem is in monitoring. I have a lag in processed offsets (lag never reaches 0).

Comment: @Natalia But it's always a single batch lag, how bad does it get?

Comment: added screenshot of lag monitoring. I'm looking how to improve it